# Comportamento estranho com ocultamento de grupos

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

Estou com uma situação estranha no meu relatório. 
Ele possui dois grupos de linhas onde o primeiro nível fica oculto e expande quando  selecionado no segundo, porém na exibição do relatório ele não aparece reduzido.

Ele está exibindo dessa forma:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E a configuração da ocultação está da seguinte forma:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Era um problema de configuração do ocultamento do grupo e não na linha

Comment: sendo assim, vale a pena você fechar a pergunta, já que não era bem um problema! (ou se for o caso, se achar válido, responder e marcá-la como aceita)